# What distribution would be expected for number rapists ( vs number of victims)?

Tags: probability, distributions

This is a horrible question to ask. But it would be useful to know (rather than someone spouting an *opinion* that 99.999% are/are not.).

It has been estimated that 18.3% of women will be raped at some point in their life time ([CDC: Sexual Violence, Facts at a glance](http://www.cdc.gov/ViolencePrevention/pdf/sv-datasheet-a.pdf)).

So to answer "how many men are (likely to be) rapists", more info is required.

There would be an upper bound of 18.3%, however some men would rape more than one woman.

So to make an estimate the percentage of men that may have committed rape on one or more women, you would need to know that type of distribution there would be.

So what would likely be the distribution for rapist like behaviour?
(One tailed normal, Pareto, something else?)

*To make things simple lets assume only for the M -> F case.

This rather subjective, so I am more than happy to rephrase if someone has suggestions how.
Also links to actual research would be ideal.

Comment: Darcy, thank you for acknowledging your cross-post, but please instead choose *one* site to post on in the SE network at a time. If you don't get a suitable answer after some time, then you can flag the question and ask that it be migrated.

Comment: @cardinal Ok. I have deleted the other one.

Comment: "There would be an upper bound of 18.3%" <- One woman could be raped by multiple (possibly all) men, so the rapist ratio might be anything from 1/(male population) to 100%.

Comment: @jona Ah true. Will need to factor that in to the final calculation.

Comment: You're suggesting continuous distributions, but you're talking about a (scaled) count. It's not likely to be any named distribution.

Comment: There's a problem in that its not clear how to define rape. A survey a few years ago came out with a statistic that X% of women had been raped, where X was a surprisingly large number. But it turned out that the question asked was (something like)  "Have you ever had sex when you didn't really want to".

Comment: Due to the intimate connection between the probability model and the answer, and the near-complete lack of information that could be employed to select any probability model over any other, this question seems tantamount to asking respondents to give their opinions about the proportion of men who are rapists. These opinions would be uninformed by essential data such as the population in question and the time period referenced. As such I am leery about keeping this thread open, but perhaps some thoughtful respondents will show how statistical ideas might be appropriately used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a zero-inflated model?

It seems reasonable to assume that the population contains a (hopefully large) number of good folks who never rape anyone, mixed together with a subpopulation of rapists that attack people according to some other as-of-yet-unspecified distribution.

Fortunately for me, I know nothing about rapists, but it might be reasonable to start by imagining that for the rapists, the rapes are "generated" by a Possion process. The underlying model--rapists attack new victims at a fixed rate-- isn't quite right, but it's probably reasonably close enough that a zero-inflated poisson model would work reasonably well.

Since the Poisson model only has one parameter ($\lambda$ controls both the mean and variance), you may  want to consider a zero-inflated negative bionomial instead, since it can handle over-dispersed (variance > mean) data too.